# python tkinter event not working for entry within a frame

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I have an entry that's within a frame. I want to pass an event from that entry.

Here is code that works, but does not include an entry in a frame:

```
import tkinter as tk
myUi= tk.Tk()
myFrame = tk.Frame(myUi)
myFrame.pack()
def printMe(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    print(value)
myEntry = tk.Entry(myUi,name='entry')
myEntry.bindtags(('.entry','Entry'))
myEntry.bind("<KeyRelease>", printMe)
myEntry.pack()
myUi.mainloop()
```

Here is code that doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
myUi= tk.Tk()
myFrame = tk.Frame(myUi)
myFrame.pack()
def printMe(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    print(value)
myEntry = tk.Entry(myFrame,name='entry')
myEntry.bindtags(('.entry','Entry'))
myEntry.bind("<KeyRelease>", printMe)
myEntry.pack()
myUi.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the entry in a frame, it's binding tag contains it's own name plus the name of its ancestors separated by periods. In this specific case, the binding tag for the entry is `.!frame.myentry`. You can see this by printing out the default bindtags before you change them (eg: `print(str(myEntry))`)

Since you are changing the binding tags for the entry to be `('.entry', 'Entry')`, any bindings on the widget itself (ie: on the binding tag `.!frame.entry`) will not be associated with the widget.